# Get token for any symbols in quotes in lexer

Tags: haskell, alex

I want to parse any symbols in quotes. I can parse words this way. How should look regexp for any symbols?

```
$alpha=[a-zA-Z]
\"$alpha+\"                        { \s -> TText (pack s)     }
```

Answer (score 0):

. - is any symbol

```
\".*\"                        { \s -> TText (pack s)     }
```

Comment: `"foo" and "bar"` is not a very good string.

Comment: Any symbol, yes. That includes other quotes.